# Program aborts after freeing previously allocated memory

Tags: c, dynamic, memory-management

I'll ask you for some help with a really really simple program which implements a search planning algorithm. Well, the problem I got is a little weird for me: after allocating memory for a simple array of characters declared locally in a function, I work over this array, it has all the expected behaviors and everything goes ok, but when I call the free() function to this array before the function ends, the program stops and abort. If someone with some experience about this problem (or not...) could help me, i'd be really thankful. Well, here follows some lines of a "simulated" code to show what I'm talking about (it's not exactly what's written, but the :

```
char* v_AllTheWorld
char* v_ReadALineOfTheWorld;

v_AllTheWorld = malloc(COLUMNS * LINES * sizeof(char)); /*LINES and COLUMNS are defined constants*/

if(v_AllTheWorld == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "..."); //etc, etc.
    exit(1);
}

v_ReadALineOfTheWorld = malloc(COLUMNS * sizeof(char)); /*the "sizeof(char)" looks useless, but there's no point in talking about that here, i guess.*/

if(v_ReadALineOfTheWorld == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "..."); //etc, etc.
    exit(1);
}

while(/*some_condition (number of lines to be read)*/)
{
    //read data string from stream and stores in v_ReadALineOfTheWorld (fscanf);
    //appends the read data to v_AllTheWorld (strncat);
}

free(v_ReadALineOfTheWorld);
/*The program is stopping right after this call in the debug.*/

return v_AllTheWorld;
```

I didn't put the head of the function, the declaration of it, and I didn't represent the stream or how the data is manipulated in details, but no other calls of "malloc" or "free" are made and all the code that is written is executed unconditionally (out of any "if" or similar). Course, the last bahavior doesn't include the allocation tests, but you got what I'm saying.

So, well, I hope I did it right asking this way, I hope I detailed the problem the right way and I hope you may help me.

Oh, I almost forgot that: as you probably noticed, the program is in C.

Comment: Can we see the content of `while` loop? I suspect you are incrementing pointer `v_ReadALineOfTheWorld` in which `free(v_ReadALineOfTheWorld)` would cause undefined behavior. Note that the pointer you are freeing should be same as the one returned from malloc.

Comment: Did you try using GDB and look at the memory locations??

Comment: Also, try `calloc(v_ReadALineOfTheWorld,0)`

Comment: When you get a crash of any kind, your first reaction should be to run the program in a debugger. It will not only help you pinpoint the location of the crash, it will also let you examine memory and variables to see what might cause the crash. If the crash is in something like `free`, you should also step though all code that modifies the memory you try to free to make sure you're not writing out of bounds, or modifying the actual pointer.

Comment: Well, i can post what's happening inside the while, but you can be sure i'm not incrementing the pointer there. Actually the only commands that use the pointer inside the loop are the functions inside the parenthesis (a fscanf and a strncat, being the seconpd paramenter of the second one). I just tried to see the value of the pointer and it's the same all the time. ^^ But thanks. And... noMAD, i didn't try any of those you said. I'll try it and say what happened, but not today. Thank you too.

Comment: Maybe writing out of bounds... i din't check that. I'll try this one too and i'll say what happened. Thank you.

Comment: Tools like valgrind, insure and purify can help spot memory errors like this.  If you can't get your hands on that software, as a quick but imperfect sanity check you could also allocate say 4k extra memory, write some "test pattern" throughout, then increment the pointer returned by malloc by 2k.  Then the existing code uses the middle part of that memory region and shouldn't overwrite the 2k at either end.  Before freeing the memory, check that the test pattern is preserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could happen if you are writing outside the bounds of `v_ReadALineOfTheWorld`.  Some `malloc` libraries store info about the `malloc`d region in a wrapper around the region, and if you corrupt that info `free` could crash.

Comment: Well, i'll try to check it. Thank you.